# Rails: Date validation with timeliness but no error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, datetime

I'm hoping my inexperience with Rails is the reason no one else seems to be experiencing this issue and that there's a simple answer.  At the moment though, I'm stumped.  The quick-and-dirty is that I have a model which represents a daily schedule (open and close times by date).  When looking for a way to validate these datetime attributes, I came across several threads here which suggested using the validates_timeliness gem which I've done.  I'd written a few simple unit tests to check the rules I wanted to my object to adhere to and while the new validation seems to work, it doesn't put anything in the errors collection for the ActiveModel object.

Model Snippet:

```
class OverrideSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :close, :open, :schedule_id, presence: true
  validates_datetime :open, :after => lambda { DateTime.now }, :after_message => "must be a future date / time"
  validates_datetime :close, :after => :open, :after_message => "must be after the open date / time"  
  attr_accessible :close, :open, :schedule_id
end
```

Unit Test snippet:

```
test "open time must be in the future" do
  assert past_override_schedule.invalid? #<--- This assert succeeds
  assert past_override_schedule.errors[:open].any? #<--- This assert fails
end

test "close time must be after open time" do
  assert close_before_open_override_schedule.invalid? #<--- This assert succeeds
  assert close_before_open_override_schedule.errors[:close].any? #<--- This assert fails
end
```

I checked the .errors collection with a puts in my unit tests for ANY keys and for the size.  There were no keys and the size was always 0.  Have I missed something simple in the syntax of my validation statements?  Is this normal, expected behavior from the timeliness gem?  I appreciate any input you may have.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
validate :future_date



def future_date
  if open <= Time.now
    errors.add(:override_schedule, "must be a future date / time")
  end
end
```

Might not be exactly the logic you need, but this is the syntax. Do the same for the second validation.